# Proper way to initialize PDAs within the Solana Anchor framework

Tags: typescript, rust, blockchain, anchor, solana

I'm trying to write a simple Solana Program using Rust/Anchor which uses a PDA, but I get a CPI error when I try to invoke it, even though there's no CPI happening (maybe the PDA account initialization?).

Here is the Program code:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("51v31qHaEQniLoYuvvtXByZcfiyvog3R2EKC39EPD52p");

#[program]
pub mod solana_sandbox {
  use super::*;
  pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, bump: u8) -> ProgramResult {
    ctx.accounts.sandbox_account.bump = bump;
    Ok(())
  }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(bump: u8)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
  #[account(mut)]
  pub signer: Signer<'info>,
  #[account(
    init,
    seeds = [b"seed".as_ref()],
    bump,
    payer = signer,
  )]
  pub sandbox_account: Account<'info, SandboxAccount>,
  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct SandboxAccount {
  pub bump: u8,
}
```

Here is the client code:

```
  const [sandboxPda, sandboxBump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress([Buffer.from('seed')], SystemProgram.programId);

  await program.rpc.initialize(
    sandboxBump,
    {
      accounts: {
        signer: keypair.publicKey,
        sandboxAccount: sandboxPda,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      },
      signers: [keypair],
      instructions: []
    });
```

When I run the above, I get the following:

```
Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account 
    Program 51v31qHaEQniLoYuvvtXByZcfiyvog3R2EKC39EPD52p invoke [1]
    8ZiyjNgnFFPyw39NyMQE5FGETTjyUhSHUVQG3oKAFZiU's signer privilege escalated
    Program 51v31qHaEQniLoYuvvtXByZcfiyvog3R2EKC39EPD52p consumed 200000 of 200000 compute units
    Program 51v31qHaEQniLoYuvvtXByZcfiyvog3R2EKC39EPD52p failed: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account
```

`8ZiyjNgnFFPyw39NyMQE5FGETTjyUhSHUVQG3oKAFZiU` is the PDA address I pass in, and I'm using `anchor-cli 0.18.0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I was using the System Program ID to derive the PDA in my client code, rather than using my actual Program ID.

Should be:

```
  const [sandboxPda, sandboxBump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress([Buffer.from('seed')], <PROGRAM_ID>);
```